# iphone: Building error precompiling app_prefix.pch

Tags: iphone, build

I dont know what happened to Xcode. I was debugging my app when after a while of writing some code I tried to compile and an error message appeared:

> Building error precompiling app_prefix.pch
> arm-apple-darwin9-gcc-4.2.1: te: no such file or directory

I had never this error before, and I am not sure how to solve it.

Comment: Can you paste the content of your app_prefix.pch ? It's usually in the "Other Sources" group in Xcode.  You may have inadvertently edited it.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Did you move your [Project Name]_prefix.pch file ? If you moved it to say, a subdirectory of the project's parent, you need to open up the target Build settings for each of your targets by double clicking on them, do a search for "pch" in the build settings, and update the path to the .pch file.

For example, if you moved your .pch file to a subdirectory "Core" which is in the project parent, then you'd change "[Project Name]_prefix.pch" in the build settings to "Core/[Project Name]_prefix.pch".

Answer (score 2):

Try to change the buid setting of the target in project propertys:

Change the option Precompile prefix header to "NO"